# Comparing two time variables with jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

This is my jQuery code. In this code `#StartTime` and `#EndTime` is form input tag id's.

The getting time format is 00:00 AM/PM.

The var starttimeval and endtimeval contain values of getting start and end time.

How do I compare these two times, example: `if(starttimeval < endtimeval){alert(message);}`

```
  $(function() {
    $('#StartTime').datetimepicker({
        datepicker : false,
        format : 'g:i A'
    });
    $('#EndTime').datetimepicker({
        datepicker : false,
        format : 'g:i A'

    });
     var starttimeval=  $("#StartTime").val();
     var endtimeval= $("#EndTime").val();

      });
```

[image: this is my form image.its show the time selection using datetimepicker plugin.]

i want only time compare functionality. example getting value of starttimeval=8:00 PM and endtimeval=9:00 AM

Comment: What does `starttimeval` and `endtimeval` look like?

Comment: @tadman `The getting time format is 00:00 AM/PM.`

Comment: I mean what do you get as actual values, not what they are *theoretically*. 12-hour time can't be compared directly. Having two specific examples would help get this right, as it wouldn't require installing the date picker to test it.

Comment: What about spanning midnight?  Is `23:00` always more than `01:00`?

Comment: when i click the submit button start time value and end time value store to variables starttimeval and endtimeval.but i need validation.so compare two times if start time less than end time give alert message.so i need time compare functionality.

Comment: what datetimepicker code are you using?

Comment: @nmkkannan: As a side-note: If you are using a plug-in other than [**http://jqueryui.com/datepicker/**](http://jqueryui.com/datepicker/) please add the missing plug-in information. It can lead to confusion as not everyone can derive what plug-in you are using. No knowing the exact plug-in also means not everyone can play around with the code trying to find a solution for you. If you are using [**http://jqueryui.com/datepicker/**](http://jqueryui.com/datepicker/) please state that and link to it as well. Adding a [**jsFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net) demonstrating your issue also helps a **lot**.

Comment: @nmkkannan your recent question got downvotes only because of the lack of attempts.

Answer (score 2):

Well, have you tried something like this :

```
var dateBegin = $('StartTime').datepicker('getDate').getTime():
var dateEnd = $('EndTime').datepicker('getDate').getTime();
if (dateBegin == dateEnd)
   // some stuff
```

Seen in the doc.
(I assume you are using datetimepicker from jquery ui)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
  var start=$("#StartTime").val();
  var starttimeval= start.split("/");
  var startdt= new Date(starttimeval[2], starttimeval[1] - 1, starttimeval[0],starttimeval[3],starttimeval[4]);

  var end=$("#StartTime").val();
  var endtimeval= end.split("/");
  var enddt= new Date(endtimeval[2], endtimeval[1] - 1, endtimeval[0],endtimeval[3],endtimeval[4]);

  if (startdt< enddt) {
    alert("startdt is before current date");
  }else{
    alert("startdtis after current date");
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Getting values from a form is going to return strings, best to convert/parse the strings into **[javascript Date objects](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date)** and compare that

```
var starttime = new Date("April 14, 2014 11:00 PM");
var endtime = new Date("April 15, 2014 1:00 AM");
```

**[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/k8S3d/)**

Whenever you start dealing with date/time comparisons and your first thought is to start parsing strings and adding `if` conditions to test for various conditions like spanning midnight....stop, just stop.

Working with dates and times is best left to established code, no need to re-invent the wheel.